# Почему не работает ссылка с onclick?

Tags: javascript

Гугловцы советуют, как делать сайт с аякс функциональностью: [A spider's view of Web 2.0](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/11/spiders-view-of-web-20.html). Делал, как по ссылке:

```
<a href=”ajax.htm?foo=32” onClick=”navigate('ajax.html#foo=32'); return false”>foo 32</a>
```

Почему все равно переходит по href, а navigate не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что, как я понимаю, функция navigate не определена. Связано это с тем, что в указанном вами блоге рассказывается о том, как грамотно оформлять ссылки с ajax запросом, чтобы сайт был правильно проиндексирован google и продолжал адекватно работать в случае отключения js скриптов. На месте navigate должна быть ваша функция, которая будет отправлять ajax запрос. Для реализации ajax я бы посоветовал jQuery, копать в сторону $.post.

Comment: Да, посмотрел, что функции navigate в firefox нет. Получилось так:
onclick="window.location='about.aspx';return false"